# Is "BEGIN TRAN" needed in order to get correct SCOPE_IDENTITY?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm using an `SqlCommand` like so:

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ... VALUES ...; SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();";
```

Is this enough, or do i need `BEGIN TRAN` etc.? (Mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16016800/939213).)

I tried it first, of course, and it works fine. But will it work correctly even if there are two simultaneous inserts? (And I'm not sure how to test *that*.)

Comment: SQL knows to return the SCOPE_IDENTITY() for THAT statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need `BEGIN TRAN`. `Scope_Identity()` functions fine without it. Even if there are "simultaneous inserts". That is the whole point of the function--to return an answer for the current scope only.

Be aware that in less than SQL Server 2012, parallelism can break `Scope_Identity()`, so you **must** use the query hint `WITH (MAXDOP 1)` on your `INSERT` statement if you want it to work properly 100% of the time. You can [read about this problem on Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/328811). (It is [theoretically fixed](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2019779) in Cumulative Update package 5 for SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1, but some people seem to think that may not be 100% true).

There is also the `OUTPUT` clause in SQL Server 2005 and up, which is another way to return data about your `INSERT`, either by sending a rowset to the client or by outputting to a table. Be aware that receiving the rowset does not actually prove the `INSERT` was properly committed... so you should probably use `SET XACT_ABORT ON;` in your stored procedure. here's an example of `OUTPUT`:

```
CREATE TABLE @AInsert(IDColumn);

INSERT dbo.TableA (OtherColumn) -- not the identity column
OUTPUT Inserted.IDColumn -- , Inserted.OtherColumn, Inserted.ColumnWithDefault
   INTO @AInsert
SELECT 'abc';

-- Do something with @AInsert, which contains all the `IDColumn` values
-- that were inserted into the table. You can insert all columns, too,
-- as shown in the comments above
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, and the caveat + workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly the answer to your question, but if you are on SQL Server 2005 and above, consider using the [OUTPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause, take a look this [so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6109866/167304) for full sample, it's simple enough to implement

```
INSERT dbo.MyTable (col1, col2, col3)
OUTPUT INSERTED.idCol
VALUES ('a', 'b', 'c')
```

Answer (score 1):

Scope_Identity and Begin Tran work independently, begin tran is used when you might want to rollback or commit a transaction at a given point within your query.

Comment: In addition, the `INSERT` statement is contained with an implicit transaction; in other words, there is essentially a `BEGIN TRAN` before `INSERT` and a `COMMIT TRAN` between the end of `INSERT...` and `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()`